# Possible to run 64-bit system on 32-bit processor?

Tags: live-usb, 32-bit, amd-processor

I have a PC (old) using AMD processor Athlon II X2 which is 32-bit I think. I've tried booting Ubuntu x64 from LiveUSB, but it works!

Why? In my Windows Device Manager it shows x86...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A look at the [product specification of your Athlon II X2 processor](http://www.amd.com/us/products/desktop/processors/athlon-ii-x2/Pages/AMD-athlon-ii-x2-processor-model-numbers-feature-comparison.aspx)

shows:

> AMD64 Technology: YES
>
> Simultaneous 32- & 64-bit computing : YES

It's a 64 bit processor.